# I am not able to read from Excel file and store into database using asp.net in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am doing this to read :

```
private bool writetoven(string xlspath)
{
    OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString)


    try
    {
        OleDbCommand ocmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", excelConnection);
        excelConnection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader odr = ocmd.ExecuteReader();
        string vcode = "";
        string pswd = "";
        string vname = "";

        while (odr.Read())
        {
            vcode = valid(odr, 0);
            pswd = valid(odr, 1);
            vname = valid(odr, 2);

            insertdataintosql(vcode,pswd,vname);
        }
        excelConnection.Close();
        return true;
    }
    catch (DataException)
    {
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        lblmsg4.Text = "Data Inserted Sucessfully";
    }
}
```

and my connection string is like this:

```
excelConnectionString = "provider=Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=" + 
                        filepath1 + 
                        ";extended properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;'";
```

but I am getting an error as

> *The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file ''. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data.*
>
> *Line 1574: OleDbConnection excelConnection = new    OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
>
>   Line 1575:
>
>   Line 1576: excelConnection.Open();
>
>   Line 1577:
>
>   Line 1578:*

It seems like the file is still open but its not and I have checked the running process and its not there

Now what should I do? ...My Excel sheet is closed but I am getting this error

i dont have microsoft access on my com is that can be an issue

is this problem is something to do with my fileupload control that i am using??

Comment: Is there any special reason why you are calling  `excelConnection.Open();` **twice**? Furthermore I would check **TaskManager** if there is any instance of _Excel running in background_ (not visible) with your file open!

Comment: yes that was my fault sorry ... but i removed that and still not able to work

Comment: is this problem is something to do with my fileupload control that i am using??

Comment: Try using [LINQ-To-Excel](http://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/) and see if that works for you.

Comment: do you have any excel process running  in your task manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the account your web app is running under has permissions on the file.

Also, since you are not using a path, and just a filename, it might not be finding the file where it is at.  Where is the file located relative to your web application?

Does  System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath1) succeeed or fail?

Since you are dealing with a file upload:

The user is uploading from their computer through the browser, and the file is transferred to your server in the post response. See: http://blog.divergencehosting.com/2009/03/12/upload-read-parse-file-aspnet/

Even if you had the full path, you wouldn't be able to access the file on the user's computer from your server. The browser sends you a copy of the file in `uploadControl.PostedFile.InputStream;` where uploadControl is the name of your asp:FileUpload control.

You would then need to save this stream to a file location on the server, and provide this full path to the connection string.

If you used something like EPPlus to read the file instead of the OleDbConnection, you could use the in-memory stream instead of saving the file first.

Comment: System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath1) failed

Comment: yes i just figured it out that i need the whole path name.. can u tell me how to get the full path in fileuploder control? i am only getting filename

Comment: Try setting filename1 to @"D:\Vendor.xls" then if that is where it is located.  I doubt that's where your web app is so, the web app would have no idea that it just so happens that Vendor.xls isn't in the web app directory, but actually in the root of D:

Comment: You wouldn't use a filepath in a file uplaoder control.  You know I had a sneaking suspicion this was what you were trying to do, but wanted to get past the location issue first.

Comment: With a file upload, you will not have a path to the file.  The user is uploading from their computer through the browser, and the file is transferred to your server in the post response.  See: http://blog.divergencehosting.com/2009/03/12/upload-read-parse-file-aspnet/

Comment: Even if you had the full path, you wouldn't be able to access the file on the user's computer from your server.  The browser sends you a copy of the file in `uploadControl.PostedFile.InputStream;` where uploadControl is the name of your asp:FileUpload control

Comment: ok so if i use .csv file instead of excel i will face the same problem write?

Comment: Yes, if it is being uploaded.  You could consider using something besides OleDb to read your file, something like EPPlus I think supports in memory streams, so that you would still need to read from the stream, but you could skip the step of saving the file to the server from the stream, since I believe you can pass a stream directly to EPPlus.  I don't know what your plans are for the data so I don't know if that will meet your needs.

Comment: i used `uploadControl.PostedFile.InputStream;` but now its giving me exception of `Database or file is readonly`

Comment: my plan is to fetch the data from the sheet and insert it into database

Comment: 1) Are you trying to save the file, passing it to another function?  I don't know what you are doing when you say "i used".  What is throwing the exception?  2) The InputStream may not be modifyable.  You may need to juggle it to another stream or save the file.  That's really outside the scope of this question.

Comment: thanks again its working now ... i am getting the excel sheet data in my database

Answer (score 2):

Well, the error says :

> *cannot open the file ''.*

So it almost seems as if your Excel connection string isn't valid - it doesn't have a valid Excel file name in there!

When and where are you **setting** the Excel connection string??

Is the `filepath1` you use valid in that moment?

Does it contain the valid Excel file name ??

**Update:** why I don't understand is: you're passing in `xlspath` as a parameter to your method - yet, you don't seem to use that xlspath anywhere - most certainly not to concatenate together your `excelConnectionString` ....

```
private bool writetoven(string xlspath)
{
    OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString)
```

Can you put a breakpoint on this line - what does your `excelConnectionString` look like - just before your create the connection? Could it be that `xlspath` contains `vendor.xls` - but your Excel connection string just never even gets set to that value??

Comment: i am using that on a button click ... should i gave the connection string in my qus also i am uploading .xls file

Comment: the filepath1 i am getting is : `Vendor.xls`

Comment: i dont have microsoft access in my computer is thats the problem??

Comment: i am getting this `"provider=Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=Vendor.xls;extended properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;'"` on `excelConnectionString`..

Comment: @Drone Try doing System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath1) just to see if it gives you an exception.  If so, then Vendor.xls isn't accessible from your application.  Then you can rule out all other possibilities.

Comment: actually my filepath1 is only having `Vendor.xlx` not the whole path? will that be a problem??

Comment: It will if it's not in the root of the web apps directory when it runs.

Comment: and yes i am getting exception by using `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath1)` its saying `Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\Vendor.xls'.`

Comment: @Drone: maybe you need to pass the **fully qualified** path and file name - not just the file name alone....

Comment: yes i just figured it out that i need the whole path name.. can u tell me how to get the full path in fileuploder control? i am only getting filename

Answer (score 1):

Your excel file is open in the Microsoft Excel. Close the Excel window and everything will be fine.

Comment: my excel window is closed ... i don't have any opened excel file

Comment: @Drone Well, this was the case for me a hundred times.